# Why wont't my code append 'milk' to the end of the list if 'milk' isnt already in the list?

Tags: list, append

```
shopping_cart = [['tooth paste', 'q-tips', 'milk],['milk', 'candy', 'apples'],['planner', 'pencils', 'q-tips']]

for x in shopping_cart: #this is the overall list
    for i in shopping_cart: #This is the 3 inner lists?
        if shopping_cart[0:2] != 'milk': # this should check for milk in list
            shopping_cart.append('milk') # this should append milk to the end of the list if milk isnt in yet
```

Comment: Are you checking the correct thing? What does `shopping_cart[0:2]` give you on each iteration? You also appear to be looping through the same thing with different variables but not using either of them (i.e. looping through `shopping_cart` with `x` & `i`)

Comment: Have you debugged this code?

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't mentioned your expected output i'm assuming this is what you are looking for.

```
shopping_cart = [['tooth paste', 'q-tips', 'milk'],['milk', 'candy', 'apples'], 
['planner', 'pencils', 'q-tips']]

for x in shopping_cart:
    if 'milk' not in x:
        x.append('milk')
print shopping_cart
```

**Output:-**

```
[['tooth paste', 'q-tips', 'milk'], ['milk', 'candy', 'apples'], ['planner', 'pencils', 'q-tips', 'milk']]
```